# Page level Dim's for connections for functions

Tags: sql, asp.net, .net, vb.net, oledb

I have a function class that handles connections, and I've been searching to see if this is slowing me down any. I cant find anywhere that tells me where the connections are actually established.

Is this a bad way to handle my connections? They are all to different databases, some on different servers.

I want to keep the connections active as I need them since I will be doing 4+ data access events per page.

I will only be accessing 2-3 connections to databases per page (The other 3 will be ready, but not used)

Are all of these connections actually interacting with the servers? or are they just being put into an object ready for using the connection string inside of a command.

If they are each being connected to servers, I would see this as being very slow, but I'm not sure how to keep all connections on hand based on what this page is trying to accomplish.

Ignore naming for databases with some slight errors, was auto find/replaced to hide information.

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data

Public Class OleFun
    Public Shared Property Db1 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db1").ConnectionString)
    Public Shared Property Db2 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db2").ConnectionString)
    Public Shared Property Db3 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db3").ConnectionString)
    Public Shared Property Db4 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db4").ConnectionString)
    Public Shared Property Db5 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db5").ConnectionString)
    Public Shared Property Db6 As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db6").ConnectionString)

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns DataTable by passing in a string with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="SqlString"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetMyDataTableString(SqlString As String, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0) As DataTable
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim ReturnDataTable As New DataTable
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Dim DbCmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, MyConn)
        Try
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = DbCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Using Reader
                ReturnDataTable.Load(Reader)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try
        Return ReturnDataTable
    End Function 'Get a data table by passing in a query string OLEDB Style

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns Datatable by passing in a COMMAND with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyCmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetMyDataTableCmd(MyCmd As OleDbCommand, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0) As DataTable
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim ReturnDataTable As New DataTable
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Try
            MyCmd.Connection = MyConn
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = MyCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Using Reader
                ReturnDataTable.Load(Reader)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try
        Return ReturnDataTable
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns OleDbCommand by passing in a COMMAND with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' Retrieve Parameters from the command by index
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyCmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetMyParametersCmd(MyCmd As OleDbCommand, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0) As OleDbCommand
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Try
            MyCmd.Connection = MyConn
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try
        Return MyCmd
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns OleDbDataReader by passing in a COMMAND with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' Retrieve Parameters from the command by index
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyCmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetMyReaderCmd(MyCmd As OleDbCommand, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0) As OleDbDataReader
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim MyDbReader As OleDbDataReader
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Try
            MyCmd.Connection = MyConn
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            MyDbReader = MyCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding

        End Try
        Return MyDbReader
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Returns OleDbDataReader by passing in a COMMAND with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' Retrieve Parameters from the command by index
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyCmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <returns>DataTable</returns>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Function GetMyScalarCmd(MyCmd As OleDbCommand, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0) As Object
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        Dim MyReturnScalar As Object

        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Try
            MyCmd.Connection = MyConn
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            Using MyCmd
                MyReturnScalar = MyCmd.ExecuteScalar()
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
            Return Nothing
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try

        Return MyReturnScalar
    End Function

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Executes Query by passing in a COMMAND with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="MyCmd"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub CommandCmd(MyCmd As OleDbCommand, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0)
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If

        Try
            MyCmd.Connection = MyConn
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' Executes Query by passing in a String with optional Conn (Default is Db1)
    ''' ||Db1:Empty||Db2:1||Db3:2||Db4:3||Db5:4||Db6:5||
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <param name="SqlString"></param>
    ''' <param name="IncDb"></param>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub CommandString(SqlString As String, Optional IncDb As Integer = 0)
        Dim MyConn As OleDbConnection
        If IncDb = 1 Then
            MyConn = Db2
        ElseIf IncDb = 2 Then
            MyConn = Db5
        ElseIf IncDb = 3 Then
            MyConn = Db3
        ElseIf IncDb = 4 Then
            MyConn = Db4
        ElseIf IncDb = 5 Then
            MyConn = Db6
        Else
            MyConn = Db1
        End If
        Dim MyCmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, MyConn)
        Try
            If Not MyConn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                MyConn.Open()
            End If
            MyCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling

        Finally 'Happens regardless of failing or succeeding
            MyConn.Close()
        End Try

    End Sub

    ''' <summary>
    ''' CLOSES ALL CONNECTIONS (If they are open)
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Public Shared Sub CloseConns()
        'HACK OleDbConnection

        If Db2.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db2.Close()
        End If
        If Db1.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db1.Close()
        End If
        If Db3.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db3.Close()
        End If
        If Db4.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db4.Close()
        End If
        If Db5.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db5.Close()
        End If
        If Db6.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            Db6.Close()
        End If


    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you should as a general rule close the connection as soon as it is finished with and open it just before you need to do anything with your database.

Secondly your code could be made much more simplistic by using a class. Then you can create 5 instances of this class with difference connection strings:

```
Public Class DbConnector
    Private _conn As OleDbConnection

    Public Sub New(connectionString As String)
        _conn = New OleDbConnection(connectionString)
    End Sub

    Public Function GetMyDataTableString(SqlString As String) As DataTable
        Dim ReturnDataTable As New DataTable
        Dim DbCmd As New OleDbCommand(SqlString, _conn)
        Try
            If Not _conn.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                _conn.Open()
            End If
            Dim Reader As OleDbDataReader = DbCmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
            Using Reader
                ReturnDataTable.Load(Reader)
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'ErrorHandling
        Finally
            _conn.Close()
        End Try
        Return ReturnDataTable
    End Function
End Class

Dim connector1 As New DbConnector(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db1").ConnectionString)
Dim connector2 As New DbConnector(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Db2").ConnectionString)
```

There is far too much code in your post to re-write it all but this should give you a start.

Comment: I might have been to vague, but the main thing I'm asking is do these connections actually contact the server by being dimmed and not opened (making the 2-3 extra ones dimmed a huge waste of resources), and if they do connect, how to only dim if needed. I know to always close my connections, which is in each of the finalize blocks, (the closeconns function is in there for cleanup just in case). If I do Dim them only inside of the function being used, wont it still require a round trip to the server (I know it reuses the connection from the pool, but doesn't it need to re-test the connection?)